# How to create a new column incrementally, by group, in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I have different vectors like the `new.column.for.*` below, for each data.table's group and I want to use them in a new column in data.table. 
Is there a compact `data.table` way to do this? 
Merging seems quite cumbersome. Creating a new vector (like `new.column <- c(new.column.for.a, new.column.for.b, rep(NA, 10))`) and binding it with `DT` is ok, but not `data.table`ish.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(key.1 = rep(c('a','b','c'), each = 10), 
                 key.2 = rep(1:10, 3) , 
                     c = 1:30)
new.column.for.a <- c(paste0('a', 1:4), rep(NA, 6))
new.column.for.b <- c(paste0('b', 1:7), rep(NA, 3))

Desired.T <- data.table(key.1 = rep(c('a','b','c'), each = 10), 
                        key.2 = rep(1:10, 3) , 
                            c = 1:30, 
                            d = c(new.column.for.a, 
                                new.column.for.b, rep(NA, 10))
                        )
```

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong with `DT$d <- c(new.column.for.a, new.column.for.b, rep(NA, 10))` and what kind of syntax would be `data.table`ish

Comment: I want to insert `new.column.for.a` at a different point in time than `new.column.for.b`. I do not want to create a large vector for `DT$d` since it is memmory consuming.

Comment: If your data really looks like your example, then the only "data.table-ish" improvement I could think of, where you also add the column after the fact to a pre-existing table, would be to pre-allocate the column (something like `DT[,d:=NA_character_]`) and then insert whatever you felt like inserting, e.g. `DT[1:4,d:='a'][11:17,d:='b']`. (In fact, you can skip the pre-allocation step, as just defining the column on some rows will also fill `NA` of the same type in other rows, but I show that step as it's sometimes useful.) Is this what you mean? If not can you give a little more detail....

Comment: @Philip Perhaps we are getting close. Can `'a'` in `DT[1:4,d:='a']` be something outside the `DT`? If something like `DT[key.1 == 'a', d] <- new.column.for.a` could work would be great.

Comment: Actually, another idea is it looks as though you may be trying to join data from one table into another. If you have a separate table that looks like this `joinme <- data.table(key.1=c(rep('a',4),rep('b',7)),key.2=c(1:4,1:7),d=c(rep('a',4),rep('b',7)))` (try it in your REPL) then you can do `setkey(DT,key.1,key.2);  setkey(joinme,key.1,key.2); joinme[DT]` to add in the same `d` column that you manually defined. (Try that too and tell me if that's what you mean.)

Comment: Yes, but instead of using `<-` you can do `DT[key.1=='a',d:=new.column.for.a]`.

Comment: @Philip WOW!!!! That's super great. Thanks! :)  (and also facepalm on me.... duh)

Comment: Yeah, I agree with Philip that a merge seems natural here. I don't think having one more column hanging around is going to push you over your memory limit and if it does, you were already in trouble.